# Changing value type doesn't change ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to Python and am building a basic blog in django. I am trying to enable editing of individual blog posts. I have to 'get' these individual blog posts so I can edit them. So far, the system isn't liking my '.get' method and shows me a ValueError. I have tried changing the value type to int, str, float, even complex. It all either returns the same or says it doesn't like 'id' or even 'pk' if I change it to that.

Here is the code.

views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from blogs.models import BlogPost
 from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
 from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
 from .forms import PostForm




def index(request):
    """The home page for blogs"""
    blogposts = BlogPost.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'blogposts': blogposts}
    return render(request, 'blogs/index.html', context)



def blogpost(request, blogpost_id):
     """Show a single post"""
    postings = BlogPost.objects.get(id=blogpost_id)
    context = {'postings': postings}
    return render(request, 'blogs/blogpost.html', context)


def new_post(request):
     """Writ a new post to the blog"""
   if request.method != 'POST':
       # No data submitted; create a blank form.
       form = PostForm()
  else:
       # POST data submitted; process data
       form = PostForm(data=request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogs:index'))

 context = {'form': form}
 return render(request, 'blogs/new_post.html', context)


def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
    """Edit an existing entry"""
    entry = BlogPost.objects.get(id=entry_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # Initial request; pre-fill form with the current entry
        form = PostForm(instance=entry)

else:
    # POST data submitted; process data
    form = PostForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogs:blogpost', args[entry_id]))

context = {'entry': entry,  'form': form}
return render(request, 'blogs/edit_entry.html', context)
```

If you'll notice, under **def blogpost(request, blogpost_id):**, I was able to employ the .get method in the same exact way and it was successful. What's more, the .get should work as an int anyway since the link is a whole number.

models.py

```
  from django.db import models


class BlogPost(models.Model):
    """A blog post"""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)



    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string rep of model"""
        return (str(self.title + "     :   " + self.text))
```

urls.py

```
"""URL Configs for app blogs"""
from django.conf.urls import url
from blogs import views



urlpatterns = [ 

   #Home page
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),


   #Individual Postings Pages
   url(r'^(?P<blogpost_id>\d+)/$', views.blogpost, name='blogpost'),


   #New Post Page
   url(r'^new_post$', views.new_post, name='new_post'),

   #Page for editing a post
   url(r'^edit_entry/(?P<entry_id>)/$', views.edit_entry, name='edit_entry'),
```

]

For the

> `(?P<entry_id>)/$'`, I did take out the portion,\d+ , because the system read the '\' back as '\\' so I took it out.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import BlogPost


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text':''}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':80})}
```

What can I do to isolate and get the specific posts to edit them?

Thanks to anyone who answers this, in advance.

========================================================================

@Alasdair 
I did add \d+ to the url and this is what I received...

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_entry//
Using the URLconf defined in blog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in    this order:
^admin/
^ ^$ [name='index']
^ ^(?P<blogpost_id>\d+)/$ [name='blogpost']
^ ^new_post$ [name='new_post']
^ ^edit_entry/(?P<entry_id>\d+)/$ [name='edit_entry']
The current URL, edit_entry//, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django  settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Also, when I do that, it changes the behavior of the individual blog post. I get this response of the detailed view of the original post:

```
 Exception Type:      NoReverseMatch

Reverse for 'edit_entry' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit_entry/(?P<entry_id>\\d+)/$']

{% block content %}

<p>This is supposed to be for one post</p>

<p>{{ postings }}</p>



<p>Edit entry:</p>
<a href="{% url 'blogs:edit_entry' entry_id  %}">edit entry</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You should use `(?P<entry_id>\d+)` to capture the entry id. If you get an error with that, please include it in full.

Comment: @Alasdair    Thanks for responding. I did that and this is the error I get:             'Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_entry//
Using the URLconf defined in blog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^ ^edit_entry/(?P<entry_id>\d+)/$ [name='edit_entry']                                      
The current URL, edit_entry//, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.'

Comment: Your url should be
`url(r'^edit_entry/(?P<entry_id>\d+)/$', views.edit_entry, name='edit_entry')`

You are seeing 404 error on `/edit_entry//` because this is not a valid URL. It should be something like `/edit_entry/1/` (`1` is the ID of the post)

Comment: @VStoykov Thanks for answering. I entered the urls as follows: `url(r'^edit_entry/(?P<entry_id>\d+)/$', views.edit_entry, name='edit_entry')` And somehow the system reads it wrong.

Comment: First, go to the edit entry URL directly by entering `27.0.0.1:8000/edit_entry/1/` in your browser address bar. As long as you have added `\d+` back, this should work. Next, you need to fix the `{% url %} ` tag on the detail page. The error `'('',)'` tells you that `entry_id` is missing in that template context. Maybe you need `postings.id` instead.

Comment: Using different variables e.g. `entry_id`,  `blogpost_id` for the same model is confusing. In addition, you shouldn't use the plural `postings` for a single post.  Pick something like `post` for `BlogPost` instances, `post_id` for the id, then use it across all your urls, views and templates.

Answer (score 1):

The exception message you get is because you are trying to parse the empty string as an integer `int("")`. That operation makes no sense. The id pattern in the url should be at least one character.

`(?P<entry_id>)` is a completely useless pattern, since it contains no characters. It will always match an empty string `''` and pass that to your view function.

> `(?P<entry_id>)/$`, I did take out the portion,`\d+` , because the system read the `\` back as `\\` so I took it out.

That's how it's supposed to work. There's no reason to take anything out.